# Work on Git repos inside your node modules

Tags: git, github, npm, dependencies

I'm trying to change the way our team works with our own libraries to make things easier for everyone but I'm having a few problems that hopefully people will be able to help with. Any advice from your experiences is very welcome too.

These are web project using NPM to manage dependencies. The Libraries tend to be React components and alike.

Currently these private libs are built then are added to projects as dependencies from git through the package.json.

I find this makes the workflow pretty bad when you have issues in the external libraries. It means you have to fix the problem rebuild the lib then yarn upgrade the in the project you are working on then see if it works.

The idea to make this easier would be to have the option to clone the repos directly into the node modules folder meaning you could make changes and have them take effect straight away. Change branches of the lib. Make new branches. push, pull. The list of benefits is huge.

I have tried to set things up in this way by simply cloning the libraries into the main projects node modules folder. I thought this would be the answer to all my problems and I'm sure I have done this in the past...

The problem is that when I try to run git commands on the external libraries I get the info from the repo of the main project. For example if I type "git branch" I get a list of all the branches of the main project not the external library.

I have tried to check out a branch on the lib and it says it doesn't exist when it clearly does in github. I can only assume it's doing the same and referencing the git repo in the main project.

Am I going about managing these in the right way?
How do you manage and work on private libs at your company?

I'm really looking for a way I can work on a main project and a library of react components in tandem without constant rebuilding and repetitively running scripts. I need a more automated workflow.

Any ideas or insights on how you guys work would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I think I have found an answer to this myself In a GIT book. I realised what I need in this situation is git submodules! I'll leave this alive just in case anyone has any better solution they want to chime in with. Or has the same issue